# Java Program to check for similar digits

Tags: java

I need a Java program to identify similar digits for integers between 10 and 99.
For example if I input 23 and 62 the output of the program should be They have a similar digit.
I already wrote this program but it is not working properly

public class Problem {

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in) ;
    int a = scan.nextInt() ;
    int b = scan.nextInt() ;

    int l = a%10 ;
    int j = b%10 ;
    int f = a%100 ;
    int d = b%100 ;

    if (a>99 && a<10 && b>99 && b<10) {
        System.out.println("N/A") ;
    }

    if (l==j){

        System.out.println("They have a similar digit");
    }
    else if(f==d){

        System.out.println("They have a similar digit");

    }
    else if(l==d){

        System.out.println("They have a similar digit");
    }
    else if(f==j){

        System.out.println("They have a similar digit");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("They don't have similar digit");

    }
}
```

Comment: Um.. why not turn them to strings and check if any of the characters are the same?

Comment: f = a%100 ; //assuming positive input that's less than 100, this is just the input itself

Comment: Hint: output `f` and `d` and/or use a debugger

Comment: Additionally: `a>99 && a<10...` I guess you meant `||` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are computing the lower digit is correct, but the way you compute the upper one is wrong: you need to integer-divide the number by ten before obtaining the remainder:

```
int f = (a/10) % 10;
```

Since the output that you give is always the same, you would be better off combining the four conditions into one with `OR` operator, like this:

```
if ((l==j) || (f==d) || ... )
```

Comment: @MightyPork Nope, for homework assignments that's what you give as an answer. Otherwise, OP's not going to learn much.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank You i found my mistake and the program worked!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible easy solution using Strings:

```
String s1 = "" + numberOne;
String s2 = "" + numberTwo;

outer:
for(char c : s1.toCharArray()) {
  for(char d : s2.toCharArray()) {
    if(c == d) {
      System.out.println("They have the same digit.");
      break outer;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your declarations

```
    int f = a % 100;
    int d = b % 100;
```

I think you want the first digits, in which case you should use

```
    int f = a / 10;
    int d = b / 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
int f = a / 10;
int d = b / 10;
```

Also change your if condition like this:-

```
if((a>99 || a<10) && (b>99 || b<10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int l = a%10 ;
int j = b%10 ;
int f = a/10 ;    // notice the division
int d = b/10 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want || instead of && in this line:

```
  if (a>99 && a<10 && b>99 && b<10) {
```

Only rarely will a be both greater than 99 and less than 10. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check it out where n1p1 abbreviate as The first part of number one parameter as well as n2p2 and so on.

```
    if ((num1 < 10 || num1 > 99) || (num2 < 10 || num2 > 99)) {
        return false;
    }

    int n1p1 = num1 / 10;
    int n1p2 = num1 % 10;
    int n2p1 = num2 / 10;
    int n2p2 = num2 % 10;`

    n1p1 = (char) n1p1;
    n1p2 = (char) n1p2;
    n2p1 = (char) n2p1;
    n2p2 = (char) n2p2;

     if ((n1p1 == n2p1 || n1p1 == n2p2) ||
            (n1p2 == n2p1 || n1p2 == n2p2) ||
            (n2p1 == n1p1 || n2p1 == n1p2) ||
            (n2p2 == n1p1 || n2p2 == n1p2)) {

        return true;
    }
    return false;
```